# can I make a chat without implementing socketio to the entire server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, chat

I have a website right now that works great that uses express and I have a bunch of router.gets and post. I am also using mongodb so I can access the user's username using req.user.username.

Now, I want to make a chat without having to implement socketio for my entire server. I just don't need socketio running when it is not needed, and only running on pages that have the chat.

My current idea is like this: Whenever the user makes a "getChat" request I send them the chat as a JSON object. Then after the initial chat rendering, I make the users call a "waitChat" request. When someone else makes a post request to send a message I will either res.send the chat in the "waitChat" get request OR have waitChat res.send a "success" msg and then have the user make another "getChat" request, and have it be an endless cycle.

Comment: basically you need a connection between client and server, than you need "something" that will "push/ broadcast" your messages to connected clients. That "something" is "socket" an active connection between client and server. Whatever you said in second part is basically your implementation of "socket", for which you already have a framework `socket.io`, so use it.

Comment: alright, so I guess I will use socketio for this,  but how would I get the username of the user when they connect with socketio?

the problem isn't me not liking socketio, but I don't know how to combine my current express setup, and it

Comment: for every socket connection, there is an id assigned to it, and you will have to maintain which user is connected using which id. there are many examples available, google chat example in express with socket io.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I want to make a chat without having to implement socketio for my entire server.

No, you can't do it that way.  Your server literally has no idea when one of your web pages somewhere might attempt connect to your chat server.  You need to be listening all the time.

Also, it appears that you have a misconception about what it means to be listening for incoming socket.io connections because a listening server that has no connections is not doing anything and costs you nothing.  So, "running all the time" means nothing.  In fact, it would cost you more to start your server, stop your server, start it again later, etc... than to just leave it listening.  Plus your phrasing "without having to implement socketio for my entire server" also sounds like you think there's something heavyweight about just having a listening socket.io server.  That is not a heavyweight concept at all.

Besides, there's absolutely no downside to having your socket.io server just listening all the time.  If you want to authenticate an incoming socket.io connection either via a previously set cookie or with some other auth method, you can implement authentication so that only authorized users can connect.

---

I don't quite follow what you're talking about with waitChat and getChat.  The idea behind chat is that userA can send a message that will get delivered to userB.  The concept for how that works is that userA sends a message to the server and the server then delivers it to userB.

It's obviously easy for userA to send a message to the server.  That can be done any number of ways.  The question is how does the server deliver the message to userB.  As I think you know, the server can't just contact userB directly.  The ways to do this are:

1. userB regularly polls the server asking for something new
2. userB uses "long polling" which is also polling, but a specialized version where the server holds onto the polling request for awhile and then either returns when there is some data or times out and then the client has to poll again
3. userB makes a lasting webSocket or socket.io connection to the server and then the server can send data to the client over that connection at any time.

The webSocket or socket.io connection is by far the most efficient and, in fact, the whole concept was invented and added to the browser because the two polling schemes are not very efficient or scalable.

Comment: alright, so I guess I will use socketio for this,  but how would I get the username of the user when they connect with socketio?

the problem isn't me not liking socketio, but I don't know how to combine my current express setup, and it

Comment: @anduyang - Cookies are available when the socket.io connection connects.  So, the same way you would know who the user is with an http request will work for a socket.io connection.  In fact, a socket.io connection starts with an http request (which is why cookies are available).